# create several lists with position

Tags: python, list, range

I have this super simple code to generate a list in python. I want to make several lists like this

```
0: [0, 2]
1: [2, 4]
2: [4, 6]
```

it is possible . thanks

```
n = range(0,169,2)
num_list=list(n)
print (num_list)
```

Comment: What's your question? Did you mean to write _"**is it** possible **?**"_?

Comment: Is *what* possible?

Comment: What have you tried, and what research have you done? For example, if you want to break up `num_list`, have you read this question? [Splitting a Python list into a list of overlapping chunks](/q/36586897/4518341). For tips, see [ask].

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I'm learning python. Sorry for the dummy question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> {n: [n*2, n*2+2] for n in range(3)}
{0: [0, 2], 1: [2, 4], 2: [4, 6]}
```

Adjust the `range(3)` to produce however many lists you want.

If you want to be able to adjust the length of the individual lists:

```
>>> {n: list(range(n*2, n*2+4, 2)) for n in range(3)}
{0: [0, 2], 1: [2, 4], 2: [4, 6]}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the patience

Answer (score 1):

```py
num_list = []
for n in range(0, 169, 2):
  num_list.append([n, n+2])

print(num_list)
```

Does the trick.

If you want them to have dictionary keys:

```py
num_list = {}
for n in range(0, 169, 2):
  num_list[int(n/2)] = [n, n+2]

print(num_list)
```

Either way, `num_list[48]` returns `[96, 98]`.

Comment: thanks a lot. Still learning python

Comment: @youngt17 Aren't we all.

Comment: yes. That's true. I could have more research